# Can I define custom steps using a hash-table for params for a declarative pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to create a custom step as detailed here: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-custom-steps

The script looks like this:

```
// vars/buildPlugin.groovy
def call(body) {
    // evaluate the body block, and collect configuration into the object
    def config = [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = config
    body()
...
```

And I can run it like this in a *scripted* pipeline:

```
buildPlugin {
    name = 'git'
}
```

Which means in a declarative pipeline i gotta wrap it in a script block:

```
script {
    buildPlugin {
        name = 'git'
    }
}
```

I have a lot of custom scripts and groovy classes and it clutters things up to have to wrap them in script blocks in my pipeline. Can I write groovy scripts in a way the declarative pipeline can use without script{}?

EDIT:

Calling a groovy script from the pipeline like this works:

```
myCustomStep('sldkfjlskdf')
```

But I want to use a hashtable like they have in the examples:

```
# In myCustomStep.grooy
def call(body) {

    def config = [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = config
    body()
```

In order to call it now I have to do:

```
myCustomStep{
    param1 = 'sldkfjlskdf'
    param2 = 'sdfsdfsdfdf'
}
```

Doing this I get `Expected a step @ line....` and have to wrap it in a step

Is there a way to get nice named params like with the hash-table approach but not have to wrap in a step? I also tried calling it like `myCustomStep({param1 = 'sdfsdf'})` which did not work

Comment: If you try to do that then the Jenkinsfile will fail validation. Placing global var and library invocations inside `script{}` is currently a hard requirement. Agree on the opinion that the Jenkins declarative syntax does seem to introduce a lot of clutter in the Jenkinsfile.

Comment: Have you tried this without `script`? Which error did you get? According to [this article](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/02/15/declarative-notifications/) you should be able to do this.

Comment: @VitaliiVitrenko That article was written before this: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42360

Comment: I should correct my initial comment that while global vars face this restriction, your groovy classes do not face this restriction.

Comment: I have observed both have this restriction. vars and classes throw the error "expecting a step"

Answer (score 5):

you can use it also in declarative pipline without `script` wrapper

Here is example that works well:

script

```
//vars/shOut.groovy
def call(shellScript) {
  return sh(returnStdout: true, script: shellScript).trim()
}
```

Jenkinsfile

```
@Library('modelsLib') _

pipeline {
  agent { label 'master' }

  stages {
    stage('some stage') {
      steps {
        echo "hello!"
        shOut 'touch xxyyzz'
        sh 'ls -otr'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

output

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (some stage)
[Pipeline] echo
hello!
[Pipeline] sh
[test-pipeline] Running shell script
+ touch xxyyzz
[Pipeline] sh
[test-pipeline] Running shell script
+ ls -otr
total 32
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins     0 Dec 20 17:59 xxyyzz
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

Comment: Please see my edit. The issue was I was trying to pass a hash-table to the step

Answer (score 0):

Defining the closure outside of the pipeline works.

```
def buildOpts = {name = 'git'}

pipeline {
  ...
  steps {
    buildPlugin(buildOpts)
  }
}
```

hopefully that works for your case